# insufficientScopes when listing files from drive.appdata scope in Drive API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

I am unable to list files in `drive.appdata` scope.
I receive this error:
`The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces.`

`list` request [is accepted](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#auth) by `drive.appdata` scope.

Code:

```
response = self.service.files().list(q="name = 'test.txt'").execute()
```

Comment: did you change the scopes in your app, if so make sure to run authorization again to request consent for the new scope.  Please edit your question and include [example] there is not enough code here to help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `spaces='appDataFolder'` solved it:

```
response = self.service.files().list(spaces='appDataFolder',q="name = 'test.txt'").execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to search within the `appDataFolder`; [see docs here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata#search_for_files_in_the_application_data_folder).

Adapt your query to include it as a parent to the files which you want to list.

#### Example:

`response = self.service.files().list(q="name = 'test.txt' AND 'appDataFolder' in parents").execute()`

#### Update:

The query string can remain the same, and set the field `spaces` to 'appDataFolder' as suggested in the aforementioned docs.